# Ordenar un array con dos tipos de elementos, usando algun método de ordenación

Tags: java

Hola buenas me preguntaba si hay alguna forma con swap, o algun método de ordenación para poder ordenar un array cogiendo dos elementos a la vez.
Por ejemplo tengo este array

```
[4,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,0,0]
```

se supone que sería ordenar por grupos, por un lado los `4` y por otro los `5`.

Con cogiendo dos elementos a la vez sería que cogieras por ejemplo el `4`, `5` primeros (posiciones `0` y `1`) y los fueses colocando la posición `0`.

¿Sabríais decirme el pseudocódigo?

Comment: yo veo tres tipos, los 4, los 5 y los 0, ¿pretendes hacer un arreglo con los 4, otro con los 5 y otro con los 0 y al final ordenarlos en un soloarreglo?

Comment: Creo que te estás complicando demasiado, para empezar puedes usar el método burbuja y después ir probando métodos más eficientes que ya están más que probados, no reinventar la rueda